# Error al ejecutar comando apt-get: Malformed line 2 in source list

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Tengo una nueva computadora e instalé Linux Mint. Cuando intenté instalar **npm** para después instalar el **cli** de angular no me lo permite, me sale este error:

```
simon@simon:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for simon:
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Mientras buscaba en stackoverflow en inglés, algunas respuestas comentaban editar el archivo `sources.list` o crear uno nuevo, pero no funciona, no me da permiso ni para editar o cambiarlo.

**ACTUALIZAR**

ante los comentarios de varios sobre el archivo source.list esto me sale:

```
  GNU nano 2.9.3                                                            sources.list
```

## deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 19.3 *Tricia* - Release amd64 20191213]/ bionic contrib main non-free

ruta:

> root@simon:/etc/apt# l
>   apt.conf.d/  auth.conf.d/  preferences.d/  sources.list  sources.list.d/  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg~  trusted.gpg.d/
>   root@simon:/etc/apt# pwd
>   /etc/apt
>   root@simon:/etc/apt#

¿Alguna posible solución?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/178539/862177

Comment: exacto esos pasos hice  pero no funciono

Comment: que te sale cuando ingresas ```inxi -rc0``` en la terminal

Comment: Te tendría que dar permiso para editarlo o verlo si lo hiciste con `sudo`. Puedes hacer un `cat`  a ese archivo para ver su contenido y ponerlo en el cuerpo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Seguramente no tenga nada que ver, pero, ya que el error lo menciona, ¿Podrías incluir el contenido del archivo `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list` en la pregunta ? No se, por si fuera relevante y eso.

Comment: Tal y como dice @Trauma, es indispensable el contenido del archivo `i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list` para poder indicarte lo que está mal. Aún así el contenido de ese archivo es público y puedes restablecer su contenido cuando desees (redactando).

Comment: @Cuauhtli exacto intente con el sudo cuando me salio eso pero igual me dio error de autorizacion lo cual se me hizo raro porque el sudo es root.

Comment: @Trauma aqui esrta: root@simon:/etc/apt# l
apt.conf.d/  auth.conf.d/  preferences.d/  sources.list  sources.list.d/  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg~  trusted.gpg.d/
root@simon:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 19.3 _Tricia_ - Release amd64 20191213]/ bionic contrib main non-free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El contenido del archivo [`i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list`](https://launchpad.net/~i2p-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/i2p#sources-list-entries) debería ser el siguiente:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu bionic main
```

Debido a alguna modificación que hayas hecho en él, es probable que su contenido haya sido alterado provocando un error en su formato.

Ya que se trata de un archivo de un [repositorio PPA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_de_Paquete_Personal), puedes borrar su contenido de manera segura sin afectar al correcto funcionamiento del equipo (solo afectando a la actualización de algunos paquetes).

Tras borrarlo puedes volver a generar su archivo de repositorio (para recuperar la actualización de dichos paquetes) con la siguiente instrucción:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i2p-maintainers/i2p
```

O, si quieres evitar el borrado, puedes generarlo de nuevo de la siguiente manera:

```
echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu bionic main' | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list
```

Tras cualquiera de estas dos soluciones podrás hacer `sudo apt-get update` sin que se queje de este archivo de repositorio.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Sería de ayuda que mostraras el contenido de ese archivo con `cat` o cualquier otro programa.

De cualquier forma podrías abrir una terminal y editar ese archivo con:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list
```

Y ver lo que pasa en aquella linea, después guardarlo. Puedes usar cualquier editor o programa pero teniendo los permisos de superusuario.

Podrías también ver sólo lo que hay en esa línea (la segunda) con:

```
sed -n '2p' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list
```

O a partir de ahí con:

```
tail -n +2 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list
```

### Sección rebuscada e innecesaria.

Si no quieres usar el editor, luego de ejecutar alguno de los comandos anteriores, podrías utilizar `sed` para editar el mismo archivo de la siguiente manera (deberás usar `sudo`).

```
sed '2s/.*/contenido que deseas sólo que cuida escapar bien los caracteres/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-i2p-bionic.list
```

Y verás únicamente el contenido del archivo modificado (más no se modificó el archivo).

Si te gusta lo que viste, podrás utilizar el mismo comando pero con el parámetro `-i.bak` usándolo como `sed -i.bak ...` y el archivo se modificará y quedará como lo que viste anteriormente, pero dejando otro archivo de respaldo con el mismo nombre pero con extensión ".bak".